# Displaying value from a textbox by pressing "Enter" key

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text box and the user types two words in  the text box and then press Enter. Once the enter key is hit, the two words should be displayed in reverse order (i.e. second word first and first word second).
For example the user types 'Sara Waka'. The displayed text should be 'Waka Sara'.
How do I do this?

```
    <body>
    Enter Full Name: <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
    <br /><br />

    <script>
        var fname = document.getElementById("name").value;

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you show us your own progress with this task?

Comment: Split the string by the space character and then validate to make sure you have 2 elements (decide what to do if there isn't), and then swap the elements before joining again, with the space character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var nameInput = document.getElementById('name');
nameInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    var words = nameInput.value.split(' ');
    if (words.length === 2) {
      nameInput.value = words[1] + ' ' + words[0];
    }
    else {
      console.log('must be exactly 2 words');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope that this code solves your problem:

```
  <body>
      Enter Full Name: <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
      <br /><br />
      <script>
        document.addEventListener('keyup',function(event){
          var inputBox, val;
          if(event.keyCode === 13){
            inputBox = document.getElementById('name');
            val = inputBox.value;
            inputBox.value = val.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
          }
        });
     </script>
  </body>
```

Refer this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39nzxcb8/)